# ubuntu 20.04 and lensfun

Tags: 20.04, photography, darktable, photo-editing, lensfun

I just did install new ubuntu 20.04 from scratch.
However, in previous versions lensfun & exiv2 were preinstalled (I think so).
Now, there is no lensfun & exiv2 at all.
I did install the exiv2 via apt, but how can I install lensfun?

I need it for darktable, it does not recognize my camera and lenses.

How do I install lensfun?
Please help!

Comment: If you look at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=lensfun you'll note it's found in the `universe` repository (ie. community packaged) thus hasn't been included by default in any of 16.04/18.04/19.10 and likely other releases too.  `universe` is only enabled by default in flavors (which are themselves community supported).  Enable 'universe' then install (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

Comment: @guiverc thanks a lot! I learned new thinks from your comment and it solve my problem!!!!